# What is API Interface?

Tags: algorithm, api, rest, cloud

I'm currently studying computing and it tackles about API. I keep reading this term 'APIs provide an interface for communicating software' but i'm not really sure what is an interface to API? May i ask for your help to explain it?

Comment: Here, the interface means that the way you can communicate with other services. Like an Operating system provides an interface b/w Hardware and User.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i get your question right, but let me have a try:

So basically a simple architecture of building for example an app is splitting it up in front- and backend. For example, in a ToDo-List app there is a server-side software which manages all data and we have a Mobile App which shows the data to the user. The backend is an "abstract" program. I mean with that that you can't click buttons or something else. So, when you want to create a task in your frontend app you have to tell the backend (for example written in Java or Python) that you want to make this. For this you can use an API.

This is basically an Call of an Website. The backend recognizes is and loads data out of an database, manages it and displays it for example in JSON Format. This format is send to the website.

Look here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1

The app now is able to automatically get this data and manages it.

Obviously real APIs are much more complex. For example you have to authenticate, you can hand over parameters and so on. You have POST, GET, DELETE Methods.

But this is simply the basic concept of an API.

Look here to know how to create an API (for example in Java): https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Look here to know how for example an Mobile App consumes the API (in JavaScript): https://www.taniarascia.com/how-to-connect-to-an-api-with-javascript/

---

I hope i could help you :)

Best regards

Sebastian